# Rails Show Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, validationerror

I am using the following helper class

```
# Error Helper for Form
  def show_errors(object, field_name)
    if object.errors.any? && object.errors.messages[field_name][0].present?
      "<label class='error'>" + object.errors.messages[field_name][0] + "</label>"
    else
      return ""
    end
  end
```

In the Views i use the following to

```
<%= show_errors(resource, :email).html_safe %>
```

When i try to show the errors for the nested form validation errors i get the following error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Debugging in Better Errors Console i get the following

```
>> object.errors.messages
=> {:"company.name"=>["Please enter your Company Name.", "Please enter a valid Company Name with atleast 2 characters."], :name=>[], :email=>[], :password=>[]}
```

which is not accessible when i try the following in the forms

```
<%= show_errors(resource, :"company.name").html_safe %>
```

How can i access the errors through the helpers?

Comment: try this man `<%= show_errors(resource, :email).html_safe if show_errors(resource, :email)  %>`

Comment: @uzaif i am trying to display the errors for the nested models

Comment: @HarshaMV Sorry, I misunderstand what you want to do, the helper code seems correct, I guess something is wrong on preparing the nested objects in controller when the main object creation is failed. Can you provide the controller source?

Comment: I also think that your code is correct - can you add `Rails.logger.debug object.errors.messages.inspect` and `Rails.logger.debug field_name.inspect` to the `show_errors` method and show us what you get? I guess this will lead you to the source of the issue.

Comment: @SibevinWang i am using the devise default controller itself. i am just adding the nested model as `resource.build_company`

Comment: @BoraMa where should i add this? as i am using devise default controller n actions

Comment: I thought you could add it to the top of the `show_errors` helper. So that you'll find out what's exactly in the errors array and the `field_name` param.

Comment: @HarshaMV Maybe `resource.build_company` is the reason, because it would renew the nested company object in your resource object and the errors in the original company is just gone. When the resource creation fails, you should not call `resource.build_company` and keep the origin resource for error display.